# Comparison over ImmutableDictionaries

Tags: c#, immutability

`ImmutableDictionary` from [System.Collections.Immutable](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Immutable/) behaves unsatisfactorily in this snippet:

```
var idict = new Dictionary<string, int> { { "a", 1 }, { "b", 2 } }.ToImmutableDictionary();
var idict2 = new Dictionary<string, int>() { { "a", 1 }, { "b", 2 } }.ToImmutableDictionary();
var idict3 = new Dictionary<string, int>() { { "b", 2 }, { "a", 1 } }.ToImmutableDictionary();
var idict4 = new Dictionary<string, int>() { { "a", 2 }, { "b", 1 } }.ToImmutableDictionary();

Console.WriteLine("true?: " + (idict == idict2).ToString());
Console.WriteLine("true?: " + (idict == idict3).ToString());
Console.WriteLine("false?: " + (idict == idict4).ToString());
```

The results are:

```
true?: False
true?: False
false?: False
```

Why is that? Why can't I [treat these objects as values](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-6BsiVyC1kM) -- if they are, you know, immutable?

Comment: I guess because the framework designers did not chose to make it so. Anything else to your question?

Comment: I like these classes a lot -- I just wonder why are there these quirks as I think they obviously has to be forced upon library creators somehow.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about reading the minds of the designers of this class.

Answer (score 2):

There is a page in the C# programming guide dedicated to this question: [Guidelines for Overriding Equals() and Operator ==](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173147.aspx). The important part is:

> By default, the operator == tests for reference equality by
>   determining whether two references indicate the same object.
>   Therefore, reference types do not have to implement operator == in
>   order to gain this functionality. When a type is immutable, that is,
>   the data that is contained in the instance cannot be changed,
>   overloading operator == to compare value equality instead of reference
>   equality can be useful because, as immutable objects, they can be
>   considered the same as long as they have the same value. It is not a
>   good idea to override operator == in non-immutable types.

So it seems that language convention encourages overriding `==` for this exact purpose.

However, a relatively new class `Tuple` behaves in the same way as `ImmutableDictionary`. There is a [StackOverflow discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1483059/is-this-expected-c-sharp-4-0-tuple-equality-behavior) about this.

I haven't found any technical reason why this is not being implemented, so I guess this is because .NET programmers are not used to structural equality. (And this is a completely valid reason why not to do this, of course.)